# Is `users` a native variable on Ansible?

Tags: ansible

```
users:
  - name: hellouser
    password: pw
    accessToken: ""
    readonly: false
  - name: hellouser2
    password: pw2
    accessToken: ""
    readonly: true
```

results in:

```
fatal: [IP]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg":
"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'name'"}
```

When `users` is changed to `users2`:

```
users2:
  - name: hellouser
    password: pw
    accessToken: ""
    readonly: false
  - name: hellouser2
    password: pw2
    accessToken: ""
    readonly: true
```

the ansible run succeeds.

**Discussion**

- The issue could be caused due to a collision between a native and
     custom variable, e.g. `users` as this issue did not occur anymore as
     the custom variable `users` was changed to `users2`. However `users` was not found in [the `What Makes A Valid Variable Name` documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#what-makes-a-valid-variable-name):

> add, append, as_integer_ratio, bit_length, capitalize, center, clear,
>   conjugate, copy, count, decode, denominator, difference,
>   difference_update, discard, encode, endswith, expandtabs, extend,
>   find, format, fromhex, fromkeys, get, has_key, hex, imag, index,
>   insert, intersection, intersection_update, isalnum, isalpha,
>   isdecimal, isdigit, isdisjoint, is_integer, islower, isnumeric,
>   isspace, issubset, issuperset, istitle, isupper, items, iteritems,
>   iterkeys, itervalues, join, keys, ljust, lower, lstrip, numerator,
>   partition, pop, popitem, real, remove, replace, reverse, rfind,
>   rindex, rjust, rpartition, rsplit, rstrip, setdefault, sort, split,
>   splitlines, startswith, strip, swapcase, symmetric_difference,
>   symmetric_difference_update, title, translate, union, update, upper,
>   values, viewitems, viewkeys, viewvalues, zfill.

- In Puppet it is possible to define global and local variables so that there is no collision between native and custom variables. According to [this documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-scopes) different variable types could be defined in Ansible:

> - Global: this is set by config, environment variables and the command line
> - Play: each play and contained structures, vars entries, include_vars, role defaults and vars.
> - Host: variables directly associated to a host, like inventory, facts or registered task outputs

*Questions*

1. How to prevent collisions between native and custom variables in
   Ansible?
2. Is there a list of native variables in Ansible?
3. Are there global and local variables in Ansible like in Puppet?

Comment: can you add the tasks which caused the error?

Comment: @knowhy https://github.com/030/ansible-sensu

Comment: puh, the problem is in the template. The datestructure you are using is a list of dictionaries if I'm not wrong. You might need a second `for` loop... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373154/list-of-dictionary-in-jinja-template

Comment: @knowhy `for user in uchiwa_users` works. If `uchiwa_users` is changed to `users` it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the tasks which raised the `"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'name'"` error it is hard to tell what went wrong here. I can't reproduce this error so I guess it is a bug in the module you are using.

Beside the already quoted [list](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#what-makes-a-valid-variable-name) of `known public attributes` there are no further rules I'm aware of. Even using `known public attributes` did not lead to any errors in my tests.

Ansible has the concept of [magic variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) which are basically just facts gathered by the `setup` module. You can get a list of the `magic variables` by running the `setup` module against the host.

There are no `global` and `local` variables in Ansible in the sense of `types`. Variables in Ansible have a `scope`. The scope of a variable depends on where it is set. Take a look at [the documentation for variable precedence](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).